# Best way to save and read user data in Flash Builder Flex mobile project

Tags: actionscript-3, mobile, settings, storage

In a mobile project, I have some edit's (5 to be exactly) and some radio buttons (but can be one because it is a group, that the user can edit that need to restore when the user reopens the app.

I know already some of the class FileReference, but is this the best way to do it? I don't prefer XML because it is simple data. Next question is: Is it allowed to save data in the local directory of the app when it is installed? Or... can I use some registry feature (like in windows) to store some user data on the phone?

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked into the `PersistenceManager` class? I think its what you're looking for...
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/managers/PersistenceManager.html

That data is stored until it is flushed (cleared) by you or the app is deleted. It persists between app launches.

http://cookbooks.adobe.com/post_Simple_data_persistence_in_a_Flex_4_5_mobile_appli-18856.html
http://devgirl.org/2011/05/18/flex-4-5-mobile-data-handling/